# What do Martial Discipline Weapons cost?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, weapons, tome-of-battle

I have questions about the price of *discipline* weapons from *Tome of Battle*.

1. What is the price of a *+1 (some discipline) dwarven waraxe*, 
   +2,000 gp or +8,000 gp?
2. Does it give me a +1 bonus to damage?
3. Can I just add the *discipline* property to a masterwork dwarven waraxe?
4. Does this mean I get +4 attack rolls?

Comment: Oh. sorry. i think i find answer
http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?147916-Martial-Discipline-Weapons-Question
but ok. can i enchant only masterwork weapon for martial discipline? for example pay only 2000gp for DisciplineDwarwenWaraxe? and how many bonus attack rolls i have in Stance of this discipline? +1 for MW and +3 for stance or use maneuer from this discipline = TOTAL 4 attack rolls ?

Comment: @KRyan You sort of generally already answered this (and a lot more) [here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/30622/8610). Mark as a duplicate?

Comment: @HeyICanChan That question is kind of a mess, and gets into Epic rules, plus there seems to be some confusion here that’s specifically about *discipline* weapons. I’m inclined to just keep them separate, personally. Unfortunately, magic item pricing is one of those things that we’re just *going* to keep getting questions about, and trying to merge them all together into one canonical question is likely to just cause more confusion than it helps. See natural-weapon questions for another case where more-or-less the same answer keeps being given for slightly-different questions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Full break-down of the price:

#### A dwarven waraxe costs 30 gp

Since we are starting with a dwarven waraxe, we need to start with its price. It is 30 gp.

#### Only masterwork weapons can be made magical

Non-masterwork weapons cannot be magic. Masterwork adds a +1 enhancement bonus to attack (only), and costs 300 gp.

So we add the 300 gp to the cost of a dwarven waraxe to get a *masterwork dwarven waraxe* costing 330 gp.

Attacks made with this dwarven waraxe are made with a +1 bonus over regular dwarven waraxes.

#### All magic weapons require that you have a +1 enhancement bonus *first*

The *discipline* property is no different in this regard. This enhancement bonus provides a +1 to attack and a +1 to damage.

The cost of magic enhancement bonuses is *x*<sup>2</sup> × 2,000 gp, where *x* is the enhancement bonus. So a +1 costs 1<sup>2</sup> × 2,000 gp = 2,000 gp. This cost is added onto the cost of the *masterwork dwarven waraxe*, so the *+1 dwarven waraxe* costs 2,330 gp.

Since it is an enhancement bonus, the attack bonus does **not** stack with the one from being masterwork, so attack rolls with the *+1 dwarven waraxe* are the same as the *masterwork dwarven waraxe* (i.e. +1 over regular dwarven waraxes). **However**, the *+1 dwarven waraxe* also adds its enhancement bonus to damage rolls, so the *+1 dwarven waraxe* does 1 damage more than the *masterwork dwarven waraxe*.

#### *Discipline* “costs” as if it was a +1 enhancement bonus.

Since *discipline* is priced as if it were a +1 enhancement bonus, and our *+1 dwarven waraxe* already has a +1 enhancement bonus, we add these together to get an effective bonus of +2. The cost of a +2 enhancement bonus is 2<sup>2</sup> × 2,000 gp = 8,000 gp, but this is the cost of the +2 bonus in total, not the cost of upgrading a +1 to a +2.

So our *+1 discipline dwarven waraxe* costs the same as a *+2 dwarven waraxe*: 8,330 gp. This is 6,000 gp more than the *+1 dwarven waraxe*.

No matter what, this weapon is always going to count as at least a *+1 dwarven waraxe*, so you still get the +1 bonus to attack and damage. If you do not know any maneuvers from the chosen discipline, that is all it does.

If you *do* know maneuvers from the discipline, though, you get +1 to attack (only) from the *discipline* property; this is an untyped bonus and so stacks with the weapon’s enhancement bonus. So if you know at least one Stone Dragon (for example) maneuver, your attacks with a *+1 stone dragon dwarven waraxe* are made with an additional +1 bonus over the *+1 dwarven waraxe* (and +2 over regular dwarven waraxes). The *discipline* property does **not** provide bonuses to damage, however, so your *+1 discipline dwarven waraxe* deals the same damage as a *+1 dwarven waraxe*, even though it costs as much as a *+2 dwarven waraxe*.

Finally, though, if you are **using** one of the maneuvers when you attack (that is, the attack is part of a strike, is improved by a boost, or you are in a stance), then the bonus increases to +3 instead of +1. So if you are initiating *mountain hammer*, a Stone Dragon strike, your attack roll with a *+1 stone dragon dwarven waraxe* has a +3 bonus above the *+1 dwarven waraxe* (and +4 over regular dwarven waraxes).

#### These are bonuses *to* rolls, not additional rolls

The *+1 discipline dwarven waraxe* gives a +1 bonus *to* attack rolls when you are using the appropriate sort of maneuver. This is just a bonus, like the one your Strength adds to your attack roll.

These bonuses do **not** confer additional attacks. See the *speed* property for an example of a special weapon property that **does** add additional attacks.

## Result: *+1 discipline dwarven waraxe* for 8,330 gp

- No knowledge of discipline’s manuevers: +1 to attack rolls, +1 to damage rolls
- Knowledge of at least one maneuver from discipline: +2 to attack rolls, +1 to damage rolls
- Actively using at least one maneuver from discipline: +4 to attack rolls, +1 to damage rolls